# most efficient way of changing an int to an X and Y direction

Tags: java, performance, coordinates

I have a set of key codes, with values (mod 4 of course), 0 to 3 corresponding to the keys down, left, up, right, in that order. I need to convert these key codes into x and y directions, with a positive x indicating a location left of the origin, and an positive y indicating a location below the origin. The way I see it, I have two ways of doing this:

using arrays:

```
int [] dx = {0, -1, 0, 1};
int [] dy = {1, 0, -1, 0};
int x = dx[kc];
int y = dy[kc];
```

or using arithmetic:

```
int x = (kc%2)*(((kc/2)%2)*2 - 1);
int y = ((kc+1)%2)*(((kc/2)%2)*-2 + 1);
```

which would be more efficient?

Comment: The efficiency difference is very minor. Which is more readable to you?

Comment: don't do premature optimization, wait until this method will appear in your profiler

Comment: As @Kon said, it is very minor. Memory functions are slightly less efficient because they need to access memory, whereas the arithmetic is handled in the ALU on the CPU. It's not such a difference that you should worry about it, unless you are working on a project where execution time is EXTREMELY crucial.

Comment: I believe @Kon got some good point here... But I want to say that you could make it better by some makro: you would use `#define GET_X(d)` and `#define GET_Y(d)` so you could read it maybe a bit better and let compiler do the work

Comment: I might have misunderstood, it looks to me like this should be values from 0 to 3, not 0 to 4.
Using arithmetic you could do `int x = 1 - kc;`  and `int y = 2 - kc;` giving results of `1, 1, -1, -1`. Your arithmetic seems needlessly complicated. Did I miss something?

Comment: @JimmyM correct, sorry about that. however, x = 1 - kc and y = 2 - kc would not return the correct values

Comment: Yeap totally missed off an important step, checking the int :) honestly I think I would just check the int and assign based on the number, I can't imagine a faster way and the arithmetical way seems wrong.
Could we see the rest of your code? If it's fairly simple (i.e. you just need directionality not speed as well) and optimisation is a real concern you could use booleans and bytes instead of ints.

Comment: Use the first method, it's much more readable. Consider using `final static` arrays so the arrays are not created every time your method runs.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the language. I would think the integer representation would be more efficient. Or better yet, if you need space you could represent directions with bit strings. You would need 4 bits for the four directions. Most ints are 4 bytes, which is 8x the storage! Then again, this probably doesn't affect anything unless you are storing a LOT of these.

I would abstract away the representation with direction methods (getDirection(), setDirection(), etc) and then try running your program with several different kinds.

Edit: woops, I meant to make this a comment, not an answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Profiling would be your friend, but, I would separate your constants out in a different way. Consider:

```
private static final int[][] directions = {
    {0, 1},
    {-1, 0},
    {0, -1},
    {1, 0}
};
```

Then you can do it as simply:

```
x = directions[kc][0];
y = directions[kc][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't really worry about the efficiency of either approach since it's very unlikely that this code will be the bottleneck in any real world application. I do however, think that the first approach one is much more readable. So if you value your maintenance and debugging time, that's the way to go.

If performance is that important, and this piece of code is critical, you should actually benchmark the two approaches. Use something like [google caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) for that.

Second, you can optimize the second approach by replacing the (somewhat slow) modulus operation with a logical AND (`x &= 0xfffffffe` is the same as `x%=2` only faster, assuming `x` is an int).  And replacing the multiplication by 2 with a logical left shift (so x<<1 instead of x*2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way to do the conversion.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Point;

public class Convert {

    public Point convertDirection(int index) {
        // 0 to 3 corresponds to the keys down, left, up, right
        Point[] directions = { new Point(0, 1), new Point(-1, 0),
                new Point(0, -1), new Point(1, 0) };
        return directions[index];
    }

}
```